# Density of random variable max{ξ1, ξ2}

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2$ be independent and equally distributed absolutely continuous random variables with density $p$.

How can I find the density of the random variable $\max(\xi_1, \xi_2)$.

Comment: Hint: Consider the chance of event $\{\xi\leq x\}$, where $\xi=\max (\xi_1, \xi_2)$ and try to write it in terms of $\xi_i$ for $i=1,2$ and then use independence and follow your nose.

Comment: What are the domains of the random variables? From the given density it cannot be deduced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum and maximum of series of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567184/minimum-and-maximum-of-series-of-random-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume the support is $\mathbb{R}$ just for my own psychological reasons; modify as necesasry.

$\{\xi \le x \} = \{\xi_1 \le x, \xi_2 \le x \}$ where $\xi = \max(\xi_1,\xi_2)$

Now $\int_{-\infty}^x dF(y)= \int_{-\infty}^x p(y) dy = P(\xi \le x) = P(\xi_1 \le x, \xi_2 \le x ) = P(\xi_1 \le x)P (\xi_2 \le x ) = [F(x)]^2$ where $F$ is the CDF of the distribution.

Can you finish from here?

Again, note that I made an assumption about the support of the random variables which as pointed out in the comments is vital information.

Comment: now I have to find F(x), right? But it's in power of 2..

Comment: Without knowing the specific distribution all we can work with is $F(x)$ but if we take the derivative of $F(x)$ wrt $x$ then we will get the pdf $f(x)$. That is $ \,\displaystyle \\\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\eta=\max\{\xi_1,\xi_2\}$, then this has cdf $F(a)=P(\eta<a)=P(\max\{{\xi_1,\xi_2\}<a})=P(\xi_1<a,\xi_2<a)=P(\xi_1<a)P(\xi_2<a)=\left[G(a)\right]^2$ with G being the cdf of $\xi$.

The pdf of $\eta$ can then be found by taking the derivative wrt a: $\frac{d}{da}[G(a)]^2=2G(a)g(a)$. In this case, the density is $p$, giving us $2G(a)p(a)$. And G can be found by integrating... $G(a)=\int_{-\infty}^a p(t)dt$.

Comment: what is G here?

Comment: It is the cumulative distribution function of $\xi$ and can be found by integrating $p$.